# Why can't there be hyperkaehler structure in 2d?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

It seems to me that there can be almost quaternionic structure on a manifold of two real dimensions, i.e., that generated by ($I,i\sigma_a$) where $I$ is the 2$\times$2 identity matrix and $\sigma_a$ are the Pauli matrices.

The three complex structures $J_a=i\sigma_a$ give rise to three Kaehler forms using
$$
\Omega_a={(J_a)_{\mu}}^{\nu}g_{\nu\rho}dx^{\nu}\wedge dx^{\rho}
$$
Why is it then true that we cannot have hyperkahler structure in two real dimensions?

Comment: You need **real** 2-by-2 matrices.

Comment: "$2d$" over $\mathbb{R}$ or over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: By 2d I mean 2 real dimensions.

Comment: @abx What is the reason I need real 2-by-2 matrices?

Comment: You want them to operate on the tangent space at each point, which is a real 2d vector space.

Comment: Your question is a reasonable one, but I think it would be more instructive for you to work out the details yourself than have an expert just tell you the answer.

Comment: Deane Yang's suggestion sounds good to me as well. While you're at try to think about the  following: *is it possible to make $\mathbb{R}^2$ into a vector space over the quaternions?* ( No, but why not?)

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I understand that this question is regarded as off-topic. I am a physicist, so it is not always clear to me which questions are regarded as research level and which are not. Thank you to @DeaneYang for explaining to me why you have voted to close the question. I have attempted to solve it, but with my limited mathematical knowledge it seems difficult, and as such I shall request to transfer this question to stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space and let $I$, $J$, $K$ be linear maps $V \to V$ such that $I^2 = J^2 = K^2 = IJK = -\operatorname{id}_V$. We can view $V$ as a $\mathbb{H}$-module by defining the map $\mathbb{H}\times V \to V$ by

$$(a + bi + cj + dk, v) \mapsto av + bIv + cJv + dKv.$$

As modules over skew-fields are free (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/686368/39599)), there is an isomorphism $V \cong \mathbb{H}^n$ for some $n$ and hence $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}V = 4n$.

If $M$ is a hyperKähler manifold, then the above argument shows that $T_pM$ has dimension $4n$ for some $n$, and therefore $M$ has dimension $4n$. In particular, $M$ cannot have dimension $2$.